# What is a sparsity pattern in a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparsity

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

---

[image: It's from Boyd-Vandenberghe book]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector is $k$-sparse if exactly $k$ values are non-zero. A sparsity pattern specifies which coordinates of the vector are non-zero.